# How to adjust an image to a carousel (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html

so i have this simple problem with Bootstrap but i have not found a solution to it and it goes like this: i want to have a carousel in my web page and i took the code from Bootstrap's official web page and i want to display 1200 x 400 images but if an image i want to display is not that size, it could be smaller or it could be bigger, what should i do to make that image fit on the space if it's not the size i want... i have tried with html specifying a width and a height but it doesn't work. Maybe this question is a little bit silly but i have not found a way and also i have tried to change the size of the image but it was unsuccesfull.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It is often recommended for slider to keep all your images same dimension. But if there is no way left to do so, you can make css adjustments.

Comment: Thanks! i did it on CSS and now it works (i hadn't tried on CSS haha)

Comment: Welcome! If you are convinced, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often recommended for slider to keep all your images same dimension. But if there is no way left to do so, you can make CSS adjustments.

For an example:
You can give same dimensions (height and width) in CSS for all those images. and use `object-fit: cover;` so that image does not squeeze.